# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python, django

I'm changing view of homepage with app names pages.
I've added pages to settings. this is how directory look like:

```
- trydjango
  - src/
    - pages/
      - __init__
      - views
    - products
    - trydjango/
      - __init__
      - settings
      - urls
    - manage
```

views' code:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def home_view(*args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello Again</h1>")
```

urls code

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from src.pages.views import home_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
]
```

and I see this error when I run server

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Comment: when you seeing this error ? while running server or migrations ?

Comment: do you have \__init\__.py at the root?

Comment: You want `from pages.views import home_view`

Comment: what do u mean by root?

Comment: no while runserver, it does not need migrate

Comment: yes bruno, but it gets error with the command you've writen

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari is right - you need another `__init__.py`, in the `src` folder, at the same level as the folders `pages` etc

Comment: ok Robin, but how I should add this __init__.py??

Comment: your directory tree is not ok. Why you add src ?

Comment: it is working for other things

Comment: and you should not add pages to settings you can keep a better directory structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to [understand what an app in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#projects-and-applications) is compared to a project.
When you register an app django will look in the project root folder when you try to import it.
Your project **root** is where your `manage.py` file is. In your case the `src` folder.
So when you want to import your views module you need to state

```
    from pages.views
```

rather than

```
    from src.pages.views
```

I suggest that you read through and follow (by coding it yourself) the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) to learn more about project structure and creating your own apps with models, urls etc.

Comment: To keep a history it would be nice to answer with a new comment and not edit your old one to state different information.

Do you want help understanding where this error is coming from anyway? Then please post it, too.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, IDE may use red underline but this code is still correct:

```
from pages.views
```